# How to list number of occurence of specific string inside a text file

Tags: bash

I can do this in Python using a long-winded method but certainly it will be quicker in bash.

I am analysing several dozen files that contain several thousand lines each. I need to make some basic analysis to get an idea on the contents. To this end, I need to make list of number of occurence of certain strings in all of these files.

The starting list of strings is: "end component", "end process", "signal", "variable". This list shall change with time.

Right now I have this:

```
find . -type f -name "*usc*.vhd" -exec wc -l {} \; | sort -rn
```

This lists the files I am interested in, along with the number of lines in each file, sorted in descending order.

Now what I need is that bash open each of these files, get the statistics for the strings I mentioned and then print it in the terminal along with the data already generated by the find, wc and sort commands. I assume that I need to use grep for this. However, it is not clear how grep can check for multiple strings and then combine the results with the existing data.

Comment: do you want total count of all strings mentioned or a separate count for each string ?. For example "end component", "end process", "signal", "variable" = 100 OR "end component=25", "end process"=25, "signal"=25, "variable"=25

Comment: separate count for each string, this will help me understand what the files contain

Comment: If you can do this in Python, do it in Python.  Properly-done Python is unlikely to be significantly more long-winded.  It's difficult to do things like this in Bash in a reliable and efficient way.  Unless you are willing to put in a lot of time learning the very many traps, pitfalls, and idiosyncrasies of shell programming; the best you can hope for is some cobbled-together thing that sort of works most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `egrep/grep`

```
egrep -o "end component|end process|signal|variable" *usc*.vhd | sort | uniq -c
```

The above command will give you output in the form:

`Count Filename:Search Term`

Give it a try and let me know if this is what you exactly need.

Comment: note that this (and the other answer using egrep) is searching for regex, so one needs to be careful that the desired strings don't contain grep metacharacters. It might be simpler to store the list of strings in a file and use grep's `-F` option

Comment: to get total count, rather than per file, grep's `-h` will elide the filename from its output

Comment: Also, be aware that counts will be wrong if strings are accidentally subsets (eg. "set" and "subset" will probably not list all the "set" or will double-count some)

Comment: final comment: `-o` option to grep is non-standard but quite widely implemented

Comment: @jhnc `grep -Fwo -e 'end component' -e 'end process' -e signal -e variable` is better.

Comment: @dan I believe for GNU grep using a set of `-e` or a single `-f` are effectively equivalent - https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c#n2602 . `-w` could well be useful depending on the exact strings used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to help you completely, but this is a start:

```
find . -type f -name "*usc*.vhd" -exec egrep "end component|end process|signal|variable" {} /dev/null \;
```

- The `egrep "s1|s2|..."` gives you the possibility to search for different search terms.
- Adding `/dev/null` is a neat trick to make `(e)grep` believe that he's looking in different files (`{}` and `/dev/null`): this forces `(e)grep` to show the filename. In case you don't care about the filename, you can just drop the `/dev/null`.

Comment: egrep, never heard of this one before. Is it different from the normal grep?

Comment: `grep --help | grep egrep`

Comment: @quantum231: `egrep` is extended `grep`, it's the same as `grep -E`.

Comment: grep --extended-regexp = egrep

Comment: The result is giving occurence of the strings, is there a way to use wc to count the number of occurence for each string in a file and then just print the total count per file for all strings in a single line, each string count separate?

Comment: When you want to count the amount of occurrences, you need to do `grep -c` (which also works with `egrep`).